relatime on mergerfs pool
I'm setting up a docker home server (Jellyfin, SVN, Future Projects) using mergerfs with tiered caching of my drives and so far it's been a slog...
While trying to get mergerfs drive pooling working, I seem to be unable to use relatime as an fstab option on the pool.
Specifically, i'm using the following fstab line
#Pool without Cache
/mnt/Drives/Disk1/Media:/mnt/Drives/Disk2/Media:/mnt/Drives/Disk3/Media /mnt/Pool-NoCache/Media fuse.mergerfs
defaults,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,category.create=eplfs,relatime,users,rw,exec,
fsname=MediaPool-NoCache 0 0

#Pool with Cache
/mnt/Drives/NVME1/Media:/mnt/Drives/Disk1/Media:/mnt/Drives/Disk2/Media:/mnt/Drives/Disk3/Media /mnt/Pool-Cache/Media 
fuse.mergerfs defaults,nonempty,allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=auto-full,cache.readdir=true,
cache.statfs=true,cache.symlinks=true,cache.entry=3,cache.attr=3,cache.negative_entry=2,
moveonenospc=true,dropcacheonclose=true,minfreespace=40G,relatime,users,rw,exec,fsname=MediaPool-Cache 0 0

Error
fuse: unknown mount option relatime

I do have relatime on the mounting of the disk it's self, so it it even needed for the pool?
UUID=DRIVE_UUID_HERE /mnt/Drives/NVME1 btrfs defaults,relatime,users,rw,exec 0 1
My reasoning for relatime over atime or noatime is that I don't need the granularity of each time the file is read, but do need some form of file access timestamping on the SSD. 'Sometime in the last day or so' granularity should be fine.
Note, i'm almost useless in linux so please answer with the according level of instruction. (Also if the below fstab entry is complete garbage, let me know where it should be improved.)
Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS
Fuse3/noble,now 3.14.0-5build1

Way behind in update. Ubuntu 20.04 is way past a .1 Please update before doing anything.

I ran apt's update and upgrade and some other prompt that was in the message after you log in that did a large update.
